# create-react-app is turning all requests to https

Tags: reactjs, request

I have an app that I made with create-react-app and it using request.js to handle API calls. There are two requests that are made to other domains and I had to edit the access-control-origin headers so that the responses from those two endpoints can be parsed.

However, since I've run `npm run build` and deployed my code to a production environment I have noticed that the requests are being sent over HTTPS and with `port 80`.

`https://mysit.com:80/api/endpoint` instead of just `http://mysit.com/api/endpoint`

The site is a public domain from an ec2. Not sure why it's doing this.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible due to same origin policy. You will need to switch your API to https too.